# trying to read emails from gmail using pythonista

Tags: python, email, unicode, gmail-imap

I am fairly new to Python and am excited that I have access to gmail using imap4

Here the code I am using to access email:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import getpass
import imaplib
import console
import collections
import re
import email
import codecs
import quopri

console.clear()
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
my password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")
address = 'sch.e@gmail.com'
print('Which email address (TO) would you like to search: ',end='')
EE = raw_input()
SS = r"(TO "+"\""+EE+"\""+r")"
mail.login(address, mypassword)
mail.select("inbox")  #select the box on gmail
print("Checking for e-mails TO ",EE)
typ, messageIDs = mail.search(None,'(SINCE "01-Jan-2014")',SS)
MIDs=messageIDs[0].split()
for mailid in MIDs[::-1]:
    resp, data = mail.fetch(mailid,'(RFC822)')
    raw_body=data[0][1]
    print(raw_body.decode('UTF-8','strict'))
    print(quopri.encodestring(raw_body))
    msg=email.message_from_string(raw_body)
    print(msg)
```

Unfortunately none of the print statements contains correct Umlaute.

(for example Beste Grüße)

Could someone please give me a hint how to deal with encodings? It looks like Utf-8 encoded text except for the "=' characters,

Thank you!!
Erik

Answer (score 0):

The email's body text has been charset-encoded into bytes that are then encoded into 7bit ASCII using MIME's [`quoted-printable`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) algorithm.  You will have to reverse the QP encoding to get the original bytes, and then you can convert them to a string using the email's charset (which is not `utf-8`, otherwise the QP encoded text would say `Beste Gr=C3=BC=C3=9Fe` instead. The charset is more likely `iso-8859-1`). The email headers will tell you the actual charset, and how the body was encoded (QP, base64, etc).  However, you are fetching only the email body, so you will need to also fetch the email headers as well, using `RFC822.HEADER`.

Let's assume the email is encoded as `ISO-8859-1` using `quoted-printable` (fetch the email headers to verify). Try this more like this to decode it:

```
raw_body=data[0][1]
raw_body=quopri.decodestring(raw_body)
raw_body=raw_body.decode('ISO-8859-1')
```

Comment: Thank you! - and you are correct, the coding is mentioned in the header and it also says "quoted printable"!!  What function do I use to decode and continue to work with the text??

Comment: Python has [Internet Data Handling](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/netdata.html) functionality, which includes `email`, `base64` and `quopri` libraries.

Comment: I enternd the complete Code into the window above - please let me know how to make this work so that Umlaute can be decoded correctly

Comment: You are still not fetching the email header, only the email body. You need to fetch both, so you can check how the email is encoded before attempting to decode it.